# How to bind more than two values in $emit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to sending more than one parameter using $emit but it given me undefined value. here is my code:

In messageService:

```
var internalScope = detachedScope.$new();
  function updateCallback(newMessage) {
    internalScope.$emit("change", angular.copy(inboxMessages), angular.copy(newMessage));
}

function observeMessages(fn) {
    return internalScope.$on('change', function (e, val, newVal) {
        fn(val, newVal);
    });
}
```

in observerService:

```
   messageboxService.observeMessages(function (messages, value) {
   console.log(value); // always given undefined        
   }
```

Can someone tell me where i am making problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to send an object with two keys,

```
 var internalScope = detachedScope.$new();
   function updateCallback(newMessage) {
      internalScope.$emit("change", {inboxMsg: angular.copy(inboxMessages), newMsg: angular.copy(newMessage)});
   }
```

and in observer service,

```
messageboxService.observeMessages(function (evt,messageData) {
   console.log(messageData.inboxMsg, messageData.newMsg); // always given undefined        
}
```

Comment: Well this need to change with all observer which already written.. I am curious why a second argument is undefined in function